# Database design - how to structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-optimization

Currently, I have one table, and it is getting populated very fast.
I have 50 devices. I gather data from each device every 30 seconds. Therefore, after we add 10,000 devices, they would generate 876,000,000 records per month-- which is a lot!

```
INSERT INTO unit_data
(`id`,`dt`,`id_unit`,`data1`,`data2`,
`ip`,`unique_id`,`loc_age`,`reason_code`,
`data3`,`data4`,`Odo`,`event_time_gmt_unix`,
`switches`,`on_off`,`data5`)
```

here are my relationships

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_unit_data_UNIQUE` `id`),
  KEY `fk_gp2` (`id_unit`),
  KEY `unit_dt_id` (`dt`,`id_unit`),
  KEY `unit_id_dt` (`id_unit`,`dt`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gp2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_unit`) REFERENCES `unit` (`id_unit`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1049392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

I am facing pretty complex queries and reports, and when I do them, our system is not responding and hitting execution timeout. (this is with 2mil+ records)

I need to rethink and re-implement the database structure. And currently I am thinking about either

- Create new table for each unit
- Create new table for each unit for each month

What would you suggest?

Comment: Unit = device, right? I wouldn't suggest creating a separate table for each device. Do your indices address the queries that you have to run?

Comment: What does the long-running query look like?

Comment: Darius, I am currently, also trying to fix the query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367719

Comment: @Melanie, why not to create new tables?

Comment: I think it's bad database structure to do so. Conceptually, you have one table that stores data on devices and that's as it should be. We need to see the query/queries that are causing problems to be able to comment on how to help, but I don't think dividing your data into separate tables is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new tables is a nice idea, but you don't need to implement it, MySql already has such tool - google for keywords "mysql+partitioning". I recommend to use it because you needn't to change your queries, mysql itself cares about it. Just add "partition by" keyword to your create table statment.

One more trick for you: I suggest you are gathering a lot of information to some big table and also select sometimes some data from it. But inserting many new rows provokes table to be locked (unavailable for selects) and rebuild indexes (I'm sure that your table is indexed). In my current project I'm doing something similar to you and I advice you to do the following:

1) create table-clone of your BIG-TABLE. It should has the same structure with BIG-TABLE with one difference - table-clone doesn't has indexes.

2) when you recieve data from your devices put it into table-clone.

3) write some robot-agent which will put records from small table into big table each hour or each day - it depends to you but the best case is choose such interval that size of table will be small enough to do fullscan(remember, it isn't indexed).

4) when you want to perform SELECT query, you do it in 2 tables - in indexed BIG table - fast enough because nobody tryes to insert data into it(only robot do it sometimes), and fullscan in small table - also fast enough because you can keep it small.

5) robot should wake up in the calm time c- may be at night.

Comment: I already have a table that shows latest records, while this big table is used for reporting. so when I run my report, my server hits 100% in cpu all clients are suffering for like 30 seconds

Comment: Do you mean reporting time coincides with inserting fresh latest records from small table to big table? Because this case seems to be the only bad case. May be you should store 2 copyes of big table - BT1,BT2; write latest records into BT1 each "some_interval" hours, delete prev BT2 and replace it with new copy of BT1. Run report on BT2. Such structure quarantees your report(select)/populate(insert) queries will not intersect.